# Changing Id of django form in for loop

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm stuck in my code. Need help.

This is my front end. I am rendering forms stored in "form_list".
The problem is that the forms stored are of same type and thus produce input fields with same "id" and same "name".

This is my view:-

```
@login_required
def VideoLinkView(request):
    """view to save the video links """
    current_form_list = []
    current_form = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        vl = VideoLink.objects.filter(company=CompanyModel.objects.get(owner=request.user))
        for link in vl:
            current_form = VideoLinkForm(link.__dict__)
            current_form_list.append(current_form)
        return render(request, "premium/video_link.html", context={'form_list':current_form_list})
```

This is my html template :-

```
{% for form in form_list %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_video_link">Video Link:</label>
        {{ form.video_link }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I create different "id" and different "name" in each iteration of for loop's input tag, automatically without having knowledge of no form stored in form_list.
I tried {{ forloop.counter}} it didn't worked, perhaps I made some mistake. Also, raw python don't work in template.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How did you try forloop.counter: Try this  https://gist.github.com/vi3k6i5/764da92b65201b2706a9e6c31b63e850

Comment: you can change the default genrated `id` for each instance by using `auto_id` argument to the Form constructor

Comment: I don't think you can do this without modifying the way form_list is built. The correct way is to use `prefix` when instantiating the forms

Comment: @VikashSingh yes I tried that too as I have mentioned in the question.
It works fine for label tag but for input tag, it do not works like that.
I tried like this and few other combinations, but failed.

{% for form in form_list %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="id_video_{{ forloop.counter }}">Video {{ forloop.counter }}:</label>
              {{ form.video_link|attr:'id:id_video_{{ forloop.counter }}' }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

Comment: @MessaoudZahi
No ... if I make auto_id=False, that will give input fields with no id. I need uniques ids.

Comment: @DeepakBartwal no set `auto_id` to a string containing the format character `%s` and will generate id attributes based on the format string For example, for a format string `instance1_%s`, a field named `subject` will get the id value `instance1_subject` . do this for each instance an you will get different `id`s. [see also](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#configuring-form-elements-html-id-attributes-and-label-tags)

Comment: @DanielRoseman is there a way to to add id to the individual forms before being added to list????

Comment: Yes that is what `prefix` does. You should show the view code that is producing this list, then I can suggest how to do it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman view is added to question now.

Comment: Argh, why are you passing `link.__dict__` to the forms? In fact why are you passing anything as the data argument on a GET? Are these modelforms?

Comment: @DanielRoseman
yes .. I am passing the data which is already in the database. It is because user may want to update links.
you may neglect that.

Comment: But that is completely the wrong way to do it. Have you read any of the documentation on model forms?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Passing object.__dict__ create form with previously filled data in it.
That way we can update data data more efficiently.

Comment: yes I studied the documentation. I am still new to django.
I have studied that if you want to create forms with data already in it than we can pass those parameter in the form.

__dict__ simply pass the data of object model to form and create forms with already typed.

I prefer to pass whole object data using __dict__ over passing individual parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are creating your forms is wrong in two ways. Firstly, the first positional argument is for the values submitted by the user; passing this arg triggers validation, among other things. If you are passing values for display to prepopulate the form, you must use the `initial` kwarg:

```
current_form = VideoLinkForm(initial={...dict_of_values...})
```

However, even that is not correct for your use case here. `link` is a model instance; you should use the `instance` kwarg:

```
current_form = VideoLinkForm(instance=link)
```

Now, to solve the problem you asked, you could just pass a `prefix` as well as I originally recommended:

```
for i, link in enumerate(vl):
    current_form = VideoLinkForm(instance=link, prefix="link{}".format(i))
```

However, now that you have shown all the details, we can see that this is not the best approach. You have a queryset; so you should simply use a [model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
VideoLinkFormSet = modelformset_factory(VideoLink, form=VideoLinkForm, queryset=vl)
current_form_list = VideoLinkFormSet()
```